# React performance issue rendering of thousands of components

Tags: reactjs

We have a small react application where we have a page where we render very large xml in the collapsible tree format.

XML is about 10k Lines. We have various components for xml opening, closing tags, body and attributes and so on. This is read only xml view with only option to collapse and expand xml tags. This takes about 6-7 seconds to render.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: I guess you should lazy load your components that's one option I can think of

Comment: If your default view of the XML is "all nodes collapsed" you could try and render as shallowly as possible - i.e. rather than creating components but having them hidden (with `display: none` or similar) just don't create them at all until the relevant XML tag has been expanded. Aside from that, I'd look at your component model and see whether you actually need so many; do you need a specific "closing tag" component for example, or could that actually be handled by the tag-rendering component?

Answer (score 3):

1. Load the components only which you need ([`react loadable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable) / [`dynamic imports and React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html))
2. Re-render only those parts which you need to ([`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) with  [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback))
3. [`Before fixing re-renders, fix slow renders`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render)
4. Render only parts visible in windows([`react window`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window))